# Crear Api con NodeJs y MySql

Tags: php, nodejs, api

Amigos buen día, tengo una pequeña duda la verdad es que tengo una aplicación web en php la cual almacena en la base de datos una imagen por cada registro, por ejemplo:

```
$insertarPJ=$conexion->prepare("INSERT INTO avar(nombre, avatar, poder, 
pais) VALUES(:nombre, :avatar, :poder, :pais)");
    $insertarPJ->bindParam(':nombre', $nombre, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $insertarPJ->bindParam(':avatar', $avatar, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
    $insertarPJ->bindParam(':poder', $poder, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
    $insertarPJ->bindParam(':pais', $pais, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $insertarPJ->execute();
```

Esta parte funciona bien y en la base de datos la imagen se almacena de tipo Blob.
Pero estoy tratando de hacer una Api en NodeJs y obtener la imagen desde la base de datos he intentado de hacerlo de varias formas e incluso le he pedido ayuda al profesor de programación y tampoco a podido, este es el codigo de NodeJs para traer la imagen el cual no funciona, por favor alguna ayuda, idea o tutorial, gracias.

```
var buffer = require('buffer').Buffer;
var image;

router.get('/products', (req, res) => {
    mysqlConnection.query('SELECT * FROM avar', (err, rows, fields) => {
        if(!err) {
            // res.json(rows);
            return res.status(200).send({
                fila : rows
            });
            this.image = new buffer(blob, 'binary').toString('base64');
            console.log(this.image);
        } else {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: ¿Y cuál es el error o problema con tu código? Tu pregunta es muy amplia, trata de acotarla un poco para saber qué puede estar pasando. Por ejemplo, ¿cómo envías la imagen desde el `front`?. ¿Usando `php` puedes recuperarla? ¿Cómo?. Saludos